# Linq to SQL check for null on object before accessing property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In simple words, Is there a better way for my code? (check code below). 
 
**Detail:**
In LINQ to SQL, I have a query that contains some inner query. In that inner query i used FirstOrDefault() so now i want to check if FirstOrDefault() returned any null value then i can access property.

```
var Bills = db.BillMasters.Select(x => new BillHomeViewModel {
            ConsumerCategory = db.ConsumerCategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == x.ConsumerCategory) == null ? String.Empty : db.ConsumerCategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == x.ConsumerCategory).CategoryName                
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2) to avoid ternary operator unsupported by entity framework

```
var Bills = db.BillMasters
.Select(x => new BillHomeViewModel
{
    ConsumerCategory = db.ConsumerCategories
        .Where(c => c.ID == x.ConsumerCategory)
        .Select(c => c.CategoryName)
        .DefaultIfEmpty("")
        .FirstOrDefault()
});
```

Comment: linq-to-sql.  and First() is not supported in that case. DefaultIfEmpty works perfectly and only FirstOrDefault() works

Comment: Strange, because the documentation says that `First` is supported(well, it's not mentioned on the list of unsupported) and that `DefaultIfEmpty(arg)` is not supported. I can't check. But since docs are from 2011 they might be outdated

Comment: Error occurred: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Had to use FirstOrDefault() at the end. Now it works

Comment: @AshranHaider You should update it to FirstOrDefalut(), see the answer please

Comment: @Ksv3n yes i did it as it was obvious in that error message. I just tell that in comments so that people will know about this error.